# Finding a value in an array cache intersystems

Tags: arrays, intersystems-cache, mumps

I'm hoping someone can help I'm trying to find a way to find a value in an array exists like the PHP `in_array`.

I have two variables `PTOWN` and `ADDRESS`. I want to find if the `PTOWN` is anywhere in the array?

Comment: Can you give us more context to these variables? Is ADDRESS the array and PTOWN is the value you want to find in the array? Also, what's the format of the array? E.g. index-based like ADDRESS(0)=<index 0 value>, ADDRESS(1)=<index 1 value>, or key-based like ADDRESS(PTOWN)=<value>.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `if $data(ADDRESS("street 1")) write "found"`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `PTOWN` in the keys or the values of the nodes? If `PTOWN` might be found in the *keys*, you can use $ORDER to find the closest match to what you have. Let's say you have an array like this:

```
new PTOWN,Address,Array
set PTOWN="Paris"
set Address="Some address"
;
set Array("Paris")="123 Avenue Louis Pasteur"
set Array("Madrid")="434 Calle De Duermos"
set Array("Boston")="1522 Market Street"
;
if $ORDER(Array(PTOWN))=PTOWN d
    ...
```

[$ORDER](http://mumps.sourceforge.net/docs.html#DORDER) will return the key that matches your search term most closely and also comes after it in MUMPS' ordering system. So `$ORDER(Array("Pa"))` returns "Paris", `$ORDER(Array("Mad"))` returns "Madrid", and `$ORDER(Array("Alameda"))` returns "Boston" because "Boston" is the next thing after "Alameda" in the array.

You can use this to loop over all the keys in the array, as well:

```
new nodeName
set nodeName="" ; you have to pass $ORDER "" to get the first thing in the array
;
for  set nodeName=$ORDER(Array(nodeName)) quit:nodeName=""  d 
    ; $ORDER returns "" when you pass it the *last* key in the array, so we can quit this loop when we get that back
    ;
    if nodeName=PTOWN write Array(nodeName)
```

If `PTOWN` will be found in the values of the array, you'll have to use the loop method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that PTOWN is '$needle' and ADDRESS is '$haystack' (as per [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) documentation), and without knowing the array format, the best you can do is something like:

```
in_array(needle,haystack)
    NEW idx,found,subAry
    SET found=0 ; If you want to return 0 instead of "" if not found
    ;
    FOR $ORDER(haystack(idx)) QUIT:idx="" DO  QUIT:found
    . ; If the format of the array is: array(<index>)=<value>
    . IF haystack(idx)=needle SET found=1 QUIT
    . ;
    . ; If the format of the array is: array(<key>)=<value>
    . ; Note: this type of search can be made a bit more efficient, but we're brute-forcing here
    . IF idx=haystack SET found=1 QUIT
    . ;
    . ; If you're using nested keys and values...this is NOT recommended since Cache doesn't really support recursion
    . MERGE subAry=haystack(idx)
    . SET found=$$in_array(needle,subAry)
    ;
    QUIT found
```

You'd call it like so:

```
...=$$in_array(PTOWN,.ADDRESS) ; Don't forget to pass by reference!
```